# The effect of input current from a voltage regulator

Tags: current-measurement

I have an input voltage of 24VAC and I'm converting that to 5VDC by using a simple diode and an LM2596S-5.0 (A switching regulator powered by a simple half-wave rectifier).  I expect to draw roughly 1.5A@5VDC.  How many amps can I expect to draw from the source's perspective?  is my calculation correct to simply do:

P = VI.  P = 5*1.5, therefore I can expect a draw of around 0.3125A?

Comment: Olin's answer contains a possibly too subtle hint that you should edit your question to provide information about the part you plan to use, since it's something of a pain (and a time-sink that does not appeal) to go and do your research for you.

Comment: Even though I happen to know what an LM2596 is, the answer will vary with the type of rectifier/filter you use, and whether you are talking about RMS current or average current.

Comment: The LM2596 is just fluff detail.  My question isn't about someone doing my research for me.  It's about making sure that my general understanding of current consumption is correct and not to compute the exact drain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the details of the input (I could figure it out, but you have not mentioned the smoothing capacitor size you are going to use), you can get a decent estimate of the input current (*average*), by taking the output power and *dividing it* by the efficiency of the switcher.

From the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf), you can see the efficiency of the device with various input and output voltages:

[image: LM2596S efficiency curve]

The efficiency is only listed at 3A (there are no normalising curves against load current which most devices show). The efficiency vs. load current would show the same type of curve, incidentally.

With only one efficiency curve available, I will use it and postulate it is close to the efficiency at your load current.

As your input will be (simplistically, from a half-wave rectifier with filter, good enough for the purpose of this discussion) 16.8V peak, then at 5V out, then reading across to 5V out and 16.8v in, I get about 82% efficiency.

For your load of 1.5A on 5V, we have a *load power* of 7.5W. The total power taken by the system is 9.15W (7.5 / 0.82) where the added 1.65W is dissipated in the regulator itself and its support components.

Assuming your input is at 16.4V (it will actually be lower due to loading effects), then you will have an input current (average) of 9.15 / 16.8 = 545mA.

As I would expect the average input voltage to be a bit lower (depends on a couple of factors), there would be a slightly higher average input current.

This is where you need to be careful; depending on the input capacitor, you could have *very large* peak currents at the input, so size the rectifier diode appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely useful; even more than I was looking for tbh.  How did you compute 16.8?  It seems awfully close to a factor of 1/sqrt(2) which is somewhat similar to a un-rectified load.  Before putting a load on it, I measure roughly ~39V, but of course that's unregulated.  The source is a simple 24VAC sprinkler transformer if that helps understand where I'm coming from.

Comment: 16.8V would be the output of a half wave rectifier with no load if the ac input was centred on zero and 24Vac (rms) with a perfect diode which is as good a starting point as any. As your method is different, you get a different input to the regulator. The basic method to figure out input current remains the same

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether this LM2596S thing is a linear regulator or a switching regulator.  For a linear, the input current is the output current plus a little to run the regulator.  For a switcher, the input power is the output power plus a little to run the regulator and due to some losses.

Comment: I added more details.  So yes I understand that the chip will consume some energy and that there is some loss due to inefficiency.  That said, without calculating exactly what that inefficiency is, is the equation generally correct?  So instead of say 0.3125A it may chew up 0.35A but it's still ball-park right.